# Assistance with Threads and waiting form completion

Tags: c#

I have a question about dealing with threads. I am copying files from one folder to another, then zipping them up. Problem is the winform appears to be attempting to zip the files before they are finished copying which in turn is causing the zip function to not complete. I did some looking around on here and to be honest I am having issues wrapping my head around how it works. MSDN has a nice little snippet:

```
// Wait on a single task with no timeout specified.
        Task taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork(10000000));
        taskA.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("taskA has completed.");


static void DoSomeWork(int val)
    {
        // Pretend to do something.
        Thread.SpinWait(val);
    }
```

again it's a bit over my head the code that I am trying to wait for complete

```
error_handling("Daily Backup Started", "BackupLog.txt");
        string fileName = "";
        string Source = @"C:\folder\Program";
        string target = @"C:\folder\day_backup";
        string datestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyy-HHmm");
        string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Source, "*.mdb");
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
            string destfile = System.IO.Path.Combine(target, fileName);
            System.IO.File.Copy(file, destfile);
            sub_error_handling(fileName+" has been copied", "DailyBackupLog.txt");
        }
        compression(@"C:\backupfolder\day_backup", @"\day_backup"+datestamp+".zip");
        sub_error_handling("Files were packaged for transmission", "DailyBackupLog.txt");
```

also here is my zip code:

```
private void compression(string zipdir, string zipfilename)
    {
        try
        {
            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                zip.AddDirectory(zipdir);
                zip.Comment = "This backup was created at " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("G");
                zip.Save(zipdir + zipfilename);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            error_handling("Incremental Backup Failed Compression was unsuccessful", "Incbackuplog.txt");
            sub_error_handling(error + "", "Incbackuplog.txt");
            error_handling("End Of Error Report", "Incbackuplog.txt");
        }
    }
```

it won't let me use a void to perform the new task, so not sure what else to try. Any suggestions ?

Comment: What does your first snippit have anything to do with your problem? You have not shown that you are using threading at all in your code portion. You also have not shown us how you start the zipping process. If the problem you are having is the zipping step starts too soon, don't you think it would be a good idea to show the code that starts the zipping step?

Comment: I figured if I waited till the files finished copying and started the zip process, it would work.

Comment: Ok i edited the examples to be more complete.

Comment: Ok, now what does the threading part have to do with this. You don't use any form of multi-threading at all in your existing code. Please post the exact text of the exception you are getting when the zip fails (it looks like it is being recorded in `Incbackuplog.txt`).

Comment: ok well, according to what I know (which isn't alot to do with threading) What I need to achieve is to have the application wait till the file copy is completed so it can then zip it up. after my looking around tasks creating a new task is what I am supposed to be doing. My question is again... how can I do that ?

Comment: Your code (as shown here) ***already is waiting till the file completes.*** So the problem is elsewhere, please post the exact text of the exception as a edit so we can help you identify where that elsewhere is.

Comment: I am not getting an exception, it just copies the files, starts the zip process, and hangs there. I'll have to try a couple of other things I guess. Thanks

Comment: Looks like typical XY problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Are you sure it hung? It could just be performing the zip operation. If the files are big it could take a while.

Comment: well so far it's been 8 minutes minimum to zip up a total of 22.9mb of MDB files. I have a .tmp zipfile but it's not increasing in size. I also just tried it on another machine with a smaller database, and it worked fine. I wonder what the heck it's doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say this is causing the hang:

```
zip.AddDirectory(zipdir);
zip.Comment = "This backup was created at " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("G");
zip.Save(zipdir + zipfilename);
```

You are compressing all files in `zipdir` to a new file in the same location, so that the new file will be included in the zip file. So you are trying to include the new file *inside itself*, which is obviously impossible and explains, I think, why the zip process never ends.

By the way, you've set `zipdir` to a directory that's not the same as the one to which your code copies the files.